# Power Calculation Diff-in-Diff in R

Tags: r, statistical-power, difference-in-difference

I am planning a randomized experiment. The expected effect is a 10% increase (MDE). The model I want to use is Diff-in-Diff. I am trying to find out the minimum number of observations needed for there to be a significant effect at a 95% level with a power of 80%.

```
# Power calculations for difference-in-difference cluster randomized trials, continuous outcome
library(clusterPower)    
cpa.did.normal(alpha = 0.05, power = 0.8, 
                   nsubjects = 28, d=0.1, ICC=0.134,
                   rho_c=0.5, rho_s=0, vart=0.16)
```

This gives me the output:

> nclusters 50.17097

Am I interpreting this right to be 1'400 observations needed (28 subjects * 50 clusters)?
This number surprises me since I have seen Diff-in-Diff Papers that use way less observations in their analysis. Any advice on other methods to calculate the power? or an explanation as to why I would need so many observations?